# Getopts not properly parsing arguments

Tags: bash, shell

I have following shell script -

```
while getopts “h:f:p:u” OPTION
do
     case $OPTION in
         h)
             usage
             exit 1
             ;;
         f)
            FILE=$OPTARG
             ;;
         u)
            US=$OPTARG
             ;;
         p)
             PASSWD=$OPTARG
             ;;
         ?)
             usage
             exit
             ;;
     esac
done

echo "$FILE"
echo "$PASSWD"
echo "$US"
```

I use following commandline arguments -

```
-u root -f mydb  -p h2
```

There is no output on screen. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `while getopts “hf:p:u:” OPTION`

Comment: @Red Cricket is right. If you are expecting an argument for an option, place a : (colon) after the option flag. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to getopt should look like this ...

```
while getopts “hf:p:u:” OPTION
```

... because `h` takes no args and the other options do.